# Show that $z^2f(z)$ is bounded.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Suppose $f$ has only finite singularities and $\displaystyle \lim_{z\to \infty}zf(z)=0$. Show that there is $R>0$ such that $\displaystyle \{z^2f(z):|z|>R\}$ is bounded.

As, $\displaystyle \lim_{z\to \infty}zf(z)=0$ so for a given $\epsilon >0$ there exists $R\in \mathbb N$ such that $\displaystyle |zf(z)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|z|>R$. Thus , $zf(z)$ is bounded. But how I use the condition : " $f$ *has only finite singularities*" and show that $z^2f(z)$ is bounded ?

Please help....

Comment: @avid19 $zf(z)\to 1$?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD I can't get my powers right, I meant $\frac{1}{z^{1.1}}$.

Comment: is $f$ meromorphic? i.e. holomorphic away from the singularities.

Comment: @GiantTortoise1729 There is no connection with meromorphic..Question says _only finite singularities_. That singularities are not necessarily poles..

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "has only finite singularities"?

Comment: @ mrf ) I am also confused about this statement...But in my book the same is given.

Comment: Finitely many singularities or singularities of finite (nonzero) order i.e. poles?

Comment: the question needs restating. where is $f$ defined, what is a finite singularity?